# Why does sscanf reads only two lines with pointer to pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf

I have a file with 10 lines, and in each line there is, separated by spaces, a name, an id and an age. Problem is that when reading this file with fgets and sscanf, it returns me a seg fault when trying to read more than 2 lines.

```
typedef struct Person
{
    char t;
    long i;
    float a;
} Person;



*arrPersons = (Person*)malloc(10 * sizeof(Person));

int assignInputPeople(Person **arrPersons,  FILE *inputPeople)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char fileLine[344];
    long ID;
float ageF;
 while (fgets(fileLine, 344, inputPeople) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(fileLine, "%s %s %s", arrPersons[counter]->name,&ID)
   
    
}
```

I created a pointer to pointer for my array so that I can modify it in other functions, like this one above.

Comment: Changed it, it still doesn't work

Comment: It's under the definition of the struct

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the caller of `assignInputPeople` and the left part of `assignInputPeople`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve].

Comment: And the declaration of `arrPersons`.

Comment: And in C you don't have to (and really shouldn't) [cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: It is reallocated in the function

Comment: I just added it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing the address of `arrPersons` in the `main()` function as the argument `arrPersons` of the `assignInputPeople()` function, `arrPersons[counter]->name` is wrong because what is pointed at by `arrPersons` have only room for one elemnet, so it is out-of-range when `counter` is not `0`.

In this case, it should be `(*arrPersons)[counter].name`.

Comment: Where the line `*arrPersons = (Person*)malloc(10 * sizeof(Person))` actually is?

Comment: Also what is `capacity`?

Comment: Just do you know why I have a warning saying that my fields aren't used in my struct ?

Comment: It should be because your fields aren't used.

Comment: But when using sscanf , I use them in order to store the data in the line, like for (*arrPersons)[counter].id , or doesn't it count as accessed ?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't contain that. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Coundl't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ucbSUJNxXp50jBus) after adding some tweaks to make it compile. I'd answer "No" for the question "do you know".